# How would i send an image backward in kivy?

Tags: python, image, widget, kivy

I am trying to add a background image to my program using python and kivy. How would I go about doing that? Here is what I have so far.

My .kv file

```
BoxLayout:
    Image:
        size_hint: None, None
        source: 'pexels-photo-127673.jpeg'
        pos: self.pos
        size: self.size
    Button:
        size_hint_y: None
        height: "48dp"
        text: "Button normal"
    Button:
        size_hint_y: None
        height: "48dp"
        text: "Button down"
        state: "down"
    Button: 
        size_hint_y: None
        height: "48dp"
        text: "Button disabled"
        disabled: True
    Button:
        size_hint_y: None
        height: "48dp"
        text: "Button down disabled"
        state: "down"
        disabled: True
```

and my python file:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

class ImageBackground(Widget):
    pass

class customwidget(App):
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    customwidget().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Image` is a widget, so you are placing it in a row of the `BoxLayout`, not as its background. You must use a canvas instruction for this. Use `Rectangle` instruction and [`source`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.graphics.instructions.html#kivy.graphics.instructions.VertexInstruction.source) property to set the image:

```
BoxLayout:
    canvas.before:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: 'pexels-photo-127673.jpeg'
```